# delete lines in a file based on another file

Tags: awk, sed, gnu

I have two files named file1 and file2. I would like to delete the lines in file1 which are not in file2.

file1

```
rana     209    214 6   18  37  3   6.2
bashi    230    241 12  30  88  2.5 7.3
amir     245    250 6   14  29  2.3 4.8
joswa    190    195 6   15  45  2.5 7.5
edison   213    218 6   16  40  2.7 6.7
```

file2

```
bashi
edison
```

Desired output

```
bashi    230    241 12  30  88  2.5 7.3
edison   213    218 6   16  40  2.7 6.7
```

How can I do this with awk or sed?

Comment: While (I think) you could _probably_ convince `awk` to do it, eventually, `join -j 1 file1 file2` is a better choice for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next} $1 in a {print}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
bashi    230    241 12  30  88  2.5 7.3
edison   213    218 6   16  40  2.7 6.7
```

Reads `file2` and creates an array indexed by first field of that, then reads `file1` and if first field is in array, prints the line.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` is your friend:

```
$ grep -wFf f2 f1
bashi    230    241 12  30  88  2.5 7.3
edison   213    218 6   16  40  2.7 6.7
```

- `w` matches words.
- `F` performs fixed matching (no regex).
- `f` uses another file to get the patterns.